# Bind JSON response with dynamic keys to Java object

Tags: java, json, mongodb, bytecode, pojo

I have a json response coming from MongoDB and in its current form I have a pojo like below to bind these month field values:-

```
@JsonProperty("Feb-2017")
private Float feb2017;
```

The problem is that these month names change with time and those values will no longer be bound to the java object.The POJO in turn is an attribute of two other objects that represent this json. I cannot change the json structure in the Db and have tried creating this pojo at runtime following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178391/create-simple-pojo-classes-bytecode-at-runtime-dynamically) but I cannot figure out how to reference this object across other POJOs .

Is there any other way I could approach this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use `Map<String, Float>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your POJO, add a class member as follows:

```java
private Map<String, Object> months = new HashMap<>();
```

Then create a method annotated with `@JsonAnySetter`:

```java
@JsonAnySetter
public void set(String key, Object value) {
    months.put(key, value);
}
```

This method works as a fallback handler for all unrecognized properties found in the JSON document.