# Retrofit Dynamic json response latest not running

Tags: android, json, httprequest, retrofit, retrofit2

There is an issue in the retrofit library that I am facing in the dynamic data **JSON** response.

For example, if any key in the **JSON** is of **int** type and due to some reason the particular key type is changed to **string**. Now corresponding to the first JSON response when the key was of int type the model class was created. Now my question is I want to handle the updated string format JSON. How should I solve this task?

Below is the ApiClient class of the retrofit.

```
public class ApiClient 
{
    public static final String BASE_URL = "http:***********";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

I have got some solutions which use the rest adapter but I want to solve using the above format. How I should do please guide.

Comment: you should set the type as the string,  so you can convert to any format.

Comment: I want to handle it dynamically. How I can check response's key data type in retrofit

Comment: you define as string and when getting server response you can change into any format .but you can not change dynamically json key.

Comment: Like in the swift development which provides the alamofire network library. if let result = jsonObject["result"] as? String {
// you will be here if there is result key in jsonObject
} else {
// there is no result key in jsonObject
} Can we handle this in android when using dynamic response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create simple POJO classes (bytecode) at runtime (dynamically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178391/create-simple-pojo-classes-bytecode-at-runtime-dynamically)

Comment: Can u give any simple code @SubinBabu